# c# VideoFileWriter properties

Tags: c#, video, aforge, screen-recording

I want to record my screen while using my program.

Now I am using this code:

```
recorder.Open(pathFolder+GetCurrentDateAndTime() + ".mp4", Convert.ToInt32(System.Windows.SystemParameters.PrimaryScreenWidth), Convert.ToInt32(System.Windows.SystemParameters.PrimaryScreenHeight), 10, VideoCodec.MPEG4, 2000000);
```

The record is good but it's too fast.

What should I change to prevent it to be too fast and to be in normal speed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, initialize a timer control and assign properties to the control. Then, create a **tick** event to that timer.

videoTimer = new Timer(); videoTimer.Interval = 20; 
videoTimer.Tick += videoTimer_Tick;

vfWriter = new VideoFileWriter(); vfWriter.Open("Exported_Video.avi", 800, 600, 25, VideoCodec.MPEG4, 1000000);

Then create a start button to start the **timer**.

```
private void btnStart_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) { videoTimer.Start(); }
```

In the timer **tick** event, create a bitmap image from the size of **VideoFileWriter** and capture screen and write it to bitmap image. Then, write the image to **VideoFileWriter**.

```
private void videoTimer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e){bp = new Bitmap(800, 600); gr = Graphics.FromImage(bp);gr.CopyFromSceen(0, 0, 0, 0, new Size(bp.Width, bp.Height));
pictureBox1.Image = bp;
pictureBox1.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.StretchImage;
vfWriter.WriteVideoFrame(bp);
```

}

In the end create a stop button to stop the timer and save the file.

```
private void btnStop_Click(object sender, EventArgs e){ videoTimer.Stop();vfWriter.Close();}
```